# Doctrine cache for PHP 5.5 and higher

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I use a Symfony2 project deployed on a Ubuntu server 14.04(php version 5.5).
This version of PHP comes with Opcache built-in, so no need to install APC.

The problem is that I want to use the cache for doctrine ORM but it supports only APC,Memcached... Not Opcache

I want to install APC instead of Opcache but I noticed that APC is for PHP versions lower that 5.5
Can I run **APCu** with **Opcache** on the same server? If yes will this solve the problem or there are other better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

APC had a few use cases. Besides the same functionality the Opcache has (opcode cache), it was also a key-value storage. And that is not included in Opcache and Doctrine needs key-value storage for caching.

Therefore you have a few solutions to choose:

- [APCu](https://pecl.php.net/package/APCu) - which replaced APC in newer versions, but I think it's not so commonly used anymore.
- [Memcached](https://www.memcached.org/)
- [Redis](https://redis.io/) - similar performance to Memcached but a lot of more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [APCu](https://pecl.php.net/package/APCu), which is basically APC but without the opcode cache and supports newer PHP versions.